# Inconsistent results in reversing the order of integration

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

**Background**

When dealing with the following problem, I have come to two possible answers by following routes which (I believed) should provide me with the same answer. I am wondering why this is the case.

**The Question**

I am presented with the following set $A=\{(x,y) | 0\le x\le y \le 1 \}$ and the corresponding joint PDF:

$$ f_{XY}(x,y)=6(y-x)$$

In trying to compute the value $P(Y>2X)$, I felt as though I could integrate the joint PDF over this set with respect to y or x first by choosing freely.

**The inconsistency**

I first defined the new set $B=\{(x,y) | 0\le 2x\le y \le 1 \}$ and computed the value of the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{2x}^1 6(y-x)dydx = 0$$

This answer of $0$ is clearly incorrect and so I then computed:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{\frac{y}{2}} 6(y-x)dxdy = \frac{3}{4} $$

This answer seems much more plausible to me, however, it is unclear to me why these answers are not the same as (as far as I can tell), I am integrating in two equivalent ways.

I would be grateful for any guidance here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong upper limit for $x$ in the first calculation. It should be:

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} \int_{2x}^1 6(y-x)dydx$$

To see this, draw the area of integration. When $x$ is larger than $1/2$, the values of $y$ on the line $y=2x$ are greater than $1$ (where the PDF is zero).